# Cross-compiled QtWebkit (Qt 5.2.1) cannot handle HTML pages using RaphaelJS

Tags: qt, raphael, qt5, cross-compiling, qtwebkit

I cross-compiled Qt 5.2.1 (including ICU and QWebKit) on TI AM335x board (ARM-based).

Then I just prepared a simple `QWebView`-based application to show some HTML pages on my device.

I am able to do that for most pages, but I cannot completely show pages using [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) for some animations.

I have the suspect that the cross-compiled QtWebkit has some problems in handling this kind of javascript, and I would like to grab somehow out from `QWebView` the javascript error console, just to see where the problem is.

Maybe I am missing during cross-compilation? Some configure parameters? Please consider that the same application compiled against Qt Desktop works fine.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution: I just subclassed `QWebPage` (providing the implementation of `javaScriptConsoleMessage` function) and assigned it to my `QWebView` through `setPage()`.

Here is my code:

*mywebpage.h*:

```
#ifndef MYWEBPAGE_H
#define MYWEBPAGE_H

#include <QWebPage>
#include <QDebug>

class MyWebPage : public QWebPage
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWebPage(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    virtual void javaScriptConsoleMessage(const QString &message, int lineNumber, const QString &sourceID);

};

#endif // MYWEBPAGE_H
```

*mywebpage.cpp*:

```
#include "mywebpage.h"

MyWebPage::MyWebPage(QObject *parent) :
    QWebPage(parent)
{
}

void MyWebPage::javaScriptConsoleMessage(const QString &message, int lineNumber, const QString &sourceID)
{
    qDebug() << lineNumber << ": " << message;
}
```

and here is where I set the page of `QWebView` in my *mainwindow.cpp* (`ui->webView` is my `QWebView`):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mwp = new MyWebPage(this);
    ui->webView->setPage(mwp);
}
```

Doing so all javascript error messages are printed out on console, and I've been able to find the point in RaphaelJS where the error is generated.